# Magento2.3: Cannot add a product to wish-list even after logged in

Tags: magento2.3, css, configuration, phtml, wishlist

I'm facing an issue in adding the product to wish-list. I have logged-in the site but still can't add the product to wish-list.

When checking the admin configuration, I see the wish-list is enabled for the site but its not working.

[image]

I'm not sure, where I have to check to resolve this.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: DId you checked your error logs ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked the error logs and see the below thing [2019-11-15 09:38:20] report.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []. I believe this is not related to this issue.

Comment: Can you please check if is there any exception.log file available there or not ?

Comment: Yes, the exception.log is available there but there is no error is displaying on the file. Its empty

Comment: Can you please un-comment this line **ini_set('display_errors', 1);** in app/bootstrap.php file and then check what error you're getting there ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya, I have checked and see that I couldn't able to add configurable product to wish-list. I can add simple products without any issues. How can I rectify that?

Comment: You're getting any errors while adding config products in wishlist ?

Comment: No, I didn't get error. But, In front-end, the configurable shows out of stock even though When I create a configurable product in admin with Instock.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `Magento-2.3` version and if the product is out of stock, then it won't work.
Take a look at this issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21519.
If possible upgrade your Magento version to `2.3.4`.